# Finding the sum of the squares of the numbers from 1 to N? (Without previous sum)

Tags: java

The program I've written has a list of odd numbers on the left from 5 to 49, while the right column has the sum of squares from 1 to N (number on the left). The issue with my code is that it adds the previous sum. example:

5 || 55

7 || 195

9 || 480

```
    int s, n, sumsq;
    sumsq = 0;

    for (n = 5; n <= 49; n+= 2) {
        for(s=1; s <= n; s++)
            sumsq += (s*s);
        System.out.println(n+"\t"+sumsq);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reset `sumsq` to 0 inside your first for loop, then values won't accumulate.

```
int s, n, sumsq;


    for (n = 5; n <= 49; n+= 2) {
        sumsq = 0;
        for(s=1; s <= n; s++)
            sumsq += (s*s);
        System.out.println(n+"\t"+sumsq);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
int s, n, sumsq;
sumsq = 0;

for (n = 5; n <= 49; n+= 2) {
               sumsq = 0;
    for(s=1; s <= n; s++){
        sumsq += (s*s);
    }
    System.out.println(n+"\t"+sumsq);  
}
```

Which resets the sum.

Comment: Thank you so much! Feel stupid now that I know it was that simple, haha.

Comment: @Tony you should mark the response most useful to you as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here is the Java 8 way of doing it:-

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(5, 49)
        .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Function.identity(),
                i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, i)
                        .map(operand -> operand * operand)
                        .sum(),
                (u, v) -> null,        //if order of result doesn't matter, get rid of this
                LinkedHashMap::new))   //and this line
        .entrySet()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```